# Should we merge the tags for package repositories?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have a handful of tags related to package repositories. There's [elpa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elpa), [repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repositories), [melpa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melpa), and [marmalade](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marmalade).

How do we feel about this?

Comment: Is the question only about *repositories*, or is it about a tag for anything to do with the **Emacs package system**? I'd opt for the latter. I don't see much need for a tag that is just about repositories - most Q & A in this regard is about how to use the package system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree we should probably concentrate on a single tag.

GNU ELPA, MELPA, and Marmalade are all ELPA repositories, so `elpa` sound like the right tag name from a technical point of view.  But I guess some users may not know it, so maybe `repositories` is a better choice.  `package-repositories` is probably more clear, but also seems too long-winded.

Comment: `package-repositories` is good because it has 'package' in the name. Some people are only going to know the Emacs package manager as `package.el` or maybe even `M-x list-packages`, so just `repositories` (or `elpa`) might not be the most intuitive.

Comment: Don't forget that we can have tag synonyms.  I would agree that `package-repositories` should be the main tag (as it's specific), but `elpa` could be a synonym.  Typing `repositories` will surely bring up `package-repositories` as a search result, so it's not necessary (IMO) to make it a full-on tag synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest we make them all a synonym to [repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repositories) or [package-repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-repositories).
From the point of view of a local Emacs instance, all of them work the same way.

Of course there are viable questions one can ask about specific repositories. But none of the current questions fit that criteria, so I'd imagine the few specific questions that come up can just use [repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repositories).

Comment: For the canonical name I like `package-repositories` more than `repositories`. That way people starting to type "package" will get auto completion for all package-related tags.

Comment: Agreed, auto-completion will help avoid extra tags.  And if questions are repo specific, you can still specify that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

- [repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repositories) has the problem that it can also refer to any repository of code, from Jane Doe's GIT hub to EmacsWiki's [Elisp Area](http://www.emacswiki.org/ElispArea).
- [elpa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elpa) is accurate, but as Stefan points out, it might not be recognized by some people.
- [package-repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-repositories) is OK, but it can suffer from both weaknesses:

  - "Repository" can mean any collection.
  - "Package" can mean any library - not necessarily something usable by `package.el` - so any collection of libraries.  (There can also be confusion with other meanings of "package", besides Lisp library - especially Common Lisp packages.)

I would propose [elpa-repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elpa-repositories). What should be prominant are *two* things: (1) "package.el" or "ELPA" and (2) "repository". And just "package" here is not enough - "package.el" is needed, if we don't use "ELPA".

There is one advantage of [elpa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elpa) over [elpa-repositories](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elpa-repositories): The latter can seem to be only about the repositories, in particular, about the differences among repositories, whereas the tag is really about anything to do with the Emacs package system.

That's another possibility, I guess: [emacs-package-system](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-package-system), or even just [package-system](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-system).